# Laravel modules

Tags: php, laravel, module

I came with this modules solution and I was wondering if is anything wrong with it?

composer.json

```
"autoload" : {
    "classmap" : [
        "....",
        "app/modules"
    ],
    "psr-4" : {
        "modules\\" : "app"
    }
}
```

app/config/app.php

```
'provider' => array(
    '....',
    'Modules\ServiceProvider\ModulesServiceProvider'
```

app/modules/ModulesServiceProvider.php

```
    <?php

namespace Modules\ServiceProvider;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ModulesServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register() {
        $this->app->bind('modules', function()
        {
            return new Modules;
        });
    }

    public function boot() {

        // set modules path
        $modules_path = __DIR__ . '/';
        // scan modules directory
        $modules = scandir($modules_path);

        foreach($modules as $module)
        {
            if($module === '.' || $module === '..') continue;
            // check if module exist
            if(is_dir($modules_path) . '/' . $module)
            {
                // set routes.php path
                $routes_path = $modules_path . $module . '/routes.php';
                            // set modules views path
                $views_path = $modules_path . $module . '/views';
                // if routes.php exists
                if(file_exists($routes_path))
                {
                    // required routes.php
                    \View::addNamespace($module, $views_path);
                    require_once($routes_path);
                }
                else
                {
                    // else do ... what ??
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, I can call the views with View::make('moduleName::viewName'), routes are defined in each module which makes it easier to maintain.

If this ain't a good solution could you please explain?

Comment: Looks fine to me, but for this line:  `if($module === '.' || $module === '..') continue;`, shouldn't you be checking for 'does not equal'? Like this:  `if($module != '.' && $module != '..'){ //do not processs } else{ //process };`, That way the files with  `.` & `..` won't be included. --EDIT-- forget all that, completely forgot about the continue loop iterator, it looks good!

Comment: thanks @SteveBauman great to here that. But with this solution every time I have to include the use statement in the controllers for anything I wanna use, ex: use View; use Input; use BaseController; .... is there any issue with this technique from performance point of view?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i've done it in my package [l5-modular](https://github.com/Artem-Schander/L5Modular):

```
protected $files;

/**
 * Bootstrap the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot() {
    if(is_dir(app_path().'/Modules/')) {
        $modules = array_map('class_basename', $this->files->directories(app_path().'/Modules/'));
        foreach($modules as $module)  {

            $routes = app_path().'/Modules/'.$module.'/routes.php';
            $views  = app_path().'/Modules/'.$module.'/Views';
            $trans  = app_path().'/Modules/'.$module.'/Translations';
            if($this->files->exists($routes)) include $routes;
            if($this->files->isDirectory($views)) $this->loadViewsFrom($views, $module);
            if($this->files->isDirectory($trans)) $this->loadTranslationsFrom($trans, $module);
        }
    }
}
```